# Hiding the table when the user touches on any where on the scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I placed a `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView` and I placed a button in the `UIScrollView`, my requirement is when I tap that button I am generating a `UITableView`.

I want to hide that table when the user touches anywhere on the scroll view, but the `- touchesBegan:withEvent:` method is not working. I also tried `UITapGuestureRecogniser` but it is creating a problem when I select any row in the table view, because in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method I am taking data from the table to a text field.

Please tell me if there is any alternative for `UITableView` or any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an overlay view behind the tableview and set the `UITapGuestureRecogniser` to that view. Keep its background color as clear color so that it wont be visible to the user. You can add this view when table is getting added and remove it when user taps on this view along with the table.